# Monty Hall probability and Bayes Theory

Tags: probability

One of my colleagues came with this solution:
,,Let A be the event that the competitor wins the prize
      B be the event that car is behind the door he first selects.
Then $P(A)=P(A|B)*P(B)+P(A|B^C)*P(B^C)= \dfrac{P(A|B)}{3}+2*\dfrac{P(A|B^C)}{3}$,,
Is this a rigorous argument for solving this problem? Thank you.

Comment: A question should always be self-contained: in this case, you should recall (or at least give a web reference to) what is "Monty Python probability" (is it hte right expression ?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the Law of Total Probability at work.   (It's not Bayes' Theorem.)

$\mathsf P(B)=\tfrac 13$.   There is one prize and it is presumed to be equally likely to be behind any of the three doors from which the player selects.

So $\mathsf P(A)=\tfrac 13\mathsf P(A\mid B)+\tfrac 23\mathsf P(A\mid B^\complement)$

This leaves you with identifying the conditional probabilities if $A$ is the event that the competitor wins if... which?

- The competitor sticks with the first door?
- The competitor changes to the other unopened door?

---

**Reminder:** The Monty Hall scenario is a game show where there is one grand prize hidden behind one of three panels(or doors), and booby prizes hidden behind the other two.   The competitor is allowed to select a panel, after which the host *always* reveals a booby prize hidden behind one of other two panels (the host knows where the grand prize hides and so never reveals it).   The competitor is then asked to choose to stay with the original selection or switch to the other unrevealed panel; then wining whichever prize is revealed behind that final choice.   The task is to determine which tactic yields the highest probability of victory: *stay* or *switch*?